# Can See Keyframes, But Not Object?

Tags: rigging

So I've been working on a few animations on my desktop computer. When I open the file, I can see all of my keyframes, but my object/rig is gone?

I hope there's a solution out there! Would appreciate any suggestions to try and save my work - I've been unable to export because of this.

---

**EDIT:** Thank you to those who have replied! I've attached two images. The one without the characters is what my current file looks like. It's supposed to have two rig-characters. The second image gives you an idea of what my files typically look like.

I make animations for the Sims 3 (so the characters are additional plug-ins I've had to download). I'm noticing that more of my past animation files have the missing character rigs as well.

I hope there's a solution out there!

Thanks,

- Emily

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Could you please clarify your question? Consider uploading the .blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ As it stands, this question can not be answered.

Comment: Please show a screen capture of you work.  Show as much as possible so that readers can get learn the most about your problem before they open a file.

Comment: Yeah, we'd need to see the file, because that could be hidden geometry (alt h to show it), material data links, objects on a different layer, rigging issues, etc.